# NFC IsoDep - Initial transactions

Tags: nfc, lib-nfc

I have a NFC card that implements Mifare Plus over IsoDep, NFCa, and NDEF.
I am communicating with the card via a PC dongle, and libNfc (not android).

I have read thru the 7816-4 but am still confused as to what the first steps I should be taking when communicating with the card.  Should I for example be selecting the MF or EFDir?  Reading from these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To program reading and writing NDEF data on a Type 4 Tag requires either the NFC Forum Type 4 Tag specification or learning from existing open source code. NFC Forum specifications must now be paid for, depending on budget the other approach may be more appealing. For someone suitably familiar with the Python programming language a source of inspiration may be the Type 4 Tag reader implementation of http://nfcpy.org, in file `nfc/tag/tt4.py`.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, Stephens answer is exactly correct.  I was attempting to use standard commands from the ISO 7816-4 spec.  The NFC Forum Type 4 Tag was needed, and provides a very clear explanation of the commands to use to retrieve data.  It's basically a walkthrough.